# Hilbert representation of a bilinear form

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, linear-algebra, sp.spectral-theory, hilbert-spaces

Let $\sigma:\mathbb{R}^n\times \mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}$ be a bilinear symmetric form which is non-degenerate in the sense that for every $0\neq u\in \mathbb{R}^n$ there is $v\in \mathbb{R}^n$ with $\sigma\left(u,v\right)\ne 0$.

It is well-known and easy to see that there is a basis $e_1,...,e_n$ and $m \in \overline{0,n+1}$ such that $\sigma\left(u,v\right)= \sum_{k=1}^{m} u_kv_k-\sum_{k=m}^{n} u_kv_k$, where $v=(v_1,...,v_n)$ and $u=(u_1,...,u_n)$ with respect to $e_1,...,e_n$.

Endow $\mathbb{R}^n$ with an inner product $\langle u,v\rangle=\sum_{k=1}^{m} u_kv_k$, where $v=(v_1,...,v_n)$ and $u=(u_1,...,u_n)$ with respect to $e_1,...,e_n$. Then $T:\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}^n$ defined by $Te_k=e_k$, for $1\le k\le m$ and $Te_k=-e_k$, for $m\le k\le n$ is an isometry, such that $\sigma\left(u,v\right)=\langle Tu,v\rangle$.

I am wondering if the following infinite-dimensional version holds:

> Let $V$ be a real vector space, and let $\sigma$ be a symmetric and non-degenerate bilinear form on $V$. Can we find a Hilbert space $H$, a linear injection $S:V\to H$ and a surjective isometry $T:H\to H$ such that $\sigma\left(u,v\right)=\langle TSu,Sv\rangle_{H}$, for every $u\in V$?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is no.

Let be construct such a $(V,\sigma)$.
Let $X$ be the set of functions $\mathbf{N}\to\mathbf{R}$. Let $Y\subset X$ be a subset such that

- $Y$ is linearly independent
- $Y$ contains all Dirac functions $n\mapsto\delta_{m,n}$
- for every $g\in X$, there exists $f\in Y$ such that $\limsup(f/(|g|+1))=\infty$.

Note that the last condition forces $Y$ to be uncountable. The existence of $Y$ is checked by considering a maximal linearly independent subset containing all Dirac functions.

Now consider the space $V$ with basis indexed by $\mathbf{N}\sqcup Y$, namely $(e_n)_{n\in\mathbf{N}}$ and $(z_f)_{f\in Y}$, and symmetric bilinear form $$\sigma(e_n,e_m)=\delta_{m,n},\quad \sigma(e_n,z_f)=f(n),\quad\sigma(z_f,z_g)=0.$$

I claim that $\sigma$ is non-degenerate; I'll use the first two axioms. Indeed, let $v=\sum_na_ne_n+\sum_fb_fz_f$ belong to the kernel of $\sigma$. Then $0=\sigma(v,z_f)=\sum_na_nf(n)=0$ for all $f\in Y$. Choosing $f=\delta_n$, we deduce $a_n=0$, for all $n$. So $v=\sum_fb_fz_f$. Then $0=\sigma(v,e_n)=\sum_{f\in Y}b_ff(n)$ for all $n$, which means that $\sum_{f\in Y}b_ff=0$. Since $Y$ is linearly independent, we deduce $b_f=0$ for all $f$, and hence $v=0$.

Now suppose the existence of $H$, $S:V\to H$ and $T$ as required. Write $E_n=S(e_n)$ and $Z_f=S(z_f)$, $C_f=\|TZ_f\|$, $g(n)=\|E_n\|$.
Then for all $f\in Y$ and $n$, we have $f(n)=\sigma(z_f,e_n)=\langle TZ_f,E_n\rangle$. So $|f(n)|\le C_fg(n)$ for all $n$. Hence $\limsup (f/(g+1))<\infty$. Since this holds for each $f\in Y$, we contradict the third axiom, which ends the proof.

---

However, if $V$ has countable dimension, the answer is yes. Indeed, one can construct, by induction, an orthogonal basis and conclude in the same way as in finite dimension.

For the induction, one first observes that every finite-dimensional subspace $W$ is contained in a non-degenerate one. This allows to write $V$ as an increasing union of non-degenerate subspaces, and thereby construct the desired basis.

Comment: PS at the moment I don't know if there's always a Hilbert representation when $\sigma>0$ (i.e., $\sigma(v,v)>0$ for all $v\neq 0$).

Comment: PPS At the end of the post I used the fact that if $(V,\sigma)$ has an orthogonal basis, then it has a Hilbert representation. The converse is false. Indeed, consider an infinite dimensional separable Hilbert space itself $H$, with orthonormal Hilbert basis $(e_n)$. If $H$ had an (algebraic) orthogonal basis $(v_i)_{i\in I}$, then $I$ has to be uncountable. Write $J_n=\{i:\langle e_n,v_i\rangle\neq 0\}$. Then $J_n$ is a finite subset of $I$, so $J=\bigcup_nJ_n$ is countable. Pick $i\notin J$: then $\langle v_i,e_n\rangle=0$ for all $n$, which forces $v_i=0$, a contradiction.

Comment: If $\sigma > 0$ then $(V,\sigma)$ is an inner product space and we can simply take $H$ to be its completion, with $S$ the inclusion map and $T=I$.

Comment: @NateEldredge oh thanks, so simple :)

Comment: So, well, a necessary condition for the existence of a representation can be written as: for each sequence $(v_n)$ in $V$, there exists a positive real sequence $(t_n)$ such that for every $v\in V$, one has $|\sigma(v_n,v)|=O(t_n)$. I don't know if it's sufficient.

Comment: @YCor this condition is necessary even for a weaker condition of existing maps $S:V\to E$ and $T:V\to E^*$, where $E$ is normed, such that $\sigma(u,v)=\left<Tu,Sv\right>$. Hence, the answer is "no" for the question about "Banach representation of bilinear forms" as well.

Comment: @YCor may I suggest a couple of improvements to simplify your answer? For the proof of the countable case we don't need to envelop a subspace into a non-degenerate one, we just need a usual Gram-Schmidt procedure, if I am not missing anything. As for you counterexample I propose the following simplification: take $V=\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}}\oplus span\{ \delta_n, n\in \mathbb{N}\}$, where $\delta_n$ is viewed as a measure. Then $\sigma$ is defined by $\sigma(f\oplus \mu, g\oplus \nu) =\int f d\nu+\int g d\mu + \int\int\delta d\mu d\nu $, where $\delta$ is viewed as a function on $\mathbb{N}^2$.

Comment: Now for the sequence $v_n=0\oplus \delta_n$ the necessary condition does not hold, since we can take $v=f\oplus 0$, for $f$ growing arbitrary fast.

Comment: @erz thanks for the remarks! Indeed in my answer I make an unnecessary complication by considering a basis (of some subspace of) the space of functions, which is indeed artificial. So indeed one sets $\sigma(f,g)=0$, $\sigma(f,e_n)=f(e_n)$ and $\sigma(e_n,e_m)=\delta_{m,n}$, or denoting this with integrals as you put it.